# Why can't I use addEventListener to stop contextmenu event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to prohibit the right mouse button, but I find that if I write this:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
    return false;
}, false);
```

It will not work, the event will still work.

But if I write it like this,

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
}
```

The right mouse button will not work.

I wish to know why I can't use `addEventListener` to stop the event `contextmenu`.

Comment: what is the contextmenu?

Comment: Not all browsers allow you to disable the context menu on the whole page.

Answer (score 10):

As stated in "[Preventing the Browser's Default Action](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventpreventdefault.htm)", the return of `false` value is not enough for preventing default action. You need to call `preventDefault()` method on `Event` object:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCLf6/)

Comment: Why in this way, we use event.perventDefault(), not return false?

Comment: @qiuyuntao Not sure about why, yet the fact is `oncontextmenu` is a property on DOMElement, but `addEventListener` is a method. Maybe the browser's js engine treats them in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to `useCapture`, try passing true as the third parameter to 
`document.addEventListener()` and see if that doesn't solve it for you.